# Coldfusion parsing cfhttp.filecontent into list

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfhttp, cfloop

I am trying to parse through a `cfhttp.filecontent` that is returned and evaluate each variable.

Here is an example of what is being returned:

```
{"multicast_id":6110507831830919692,
 "success":0,
 "failure":1,
 "canonical_ids":0,
 "results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

So I would like to set to a list and loop through it so I can get the following:

```
multicast_id VARCHAR
success BIT
failure BIT
canonical_ids BIT
results VARCHAR
```

Any ideas would be great!!!

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: Stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: I've tried cflooping through using comma as a delimiter but it keeps breaking. Tried removing the quotes and it still was constantly causing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a proper CF object. `cfhttp.filecontent` is a just a string.

```
<cfscript>
data = DeserializeJSON(cfhttp.filecontent);


 writedump(data); // now you should have a proper cf variable.
</cfscript>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks James!! I Appreciate it. Here is what I was trying:

Comment: <cfset result_data = #replace(cfhttp.filecontent, "[,{,],}", "All")#>
<cfloop list="#result_data#" delimiters="," index="x">
#x#<br>
</cfloop>

Comment: You can image the mess it was making. But with cfscript above should I earmark each variable like this: data.canonial_id, data.failure, etc.???

Comment: Yes. That is how how you work your way through a struct. When you want to work through the array of structs, it will be `data.results[1].error`

Comment: James, that is perfect! Thank you so much.... I truly appreciate it!

Comment: I see you have asked lots of questions over the past few months. The the green check by the up and down votes is used indicate if an answer has been accepted.

Comment: Got it. I will go back and make sure I check those. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In tag based syntax you can use like this

```
<cfset content = cfhttp.Filecontent> 
<cfset data = DeserializeJSON(content)>
```